# Twilio Receiving Fax Host-relative URL path must start with a '/' issue on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twilio, codeigniter-3

I have created a small fax client in codeigniter 3.x and its working fine but when i setup webhooks in my twilio's number settings though the path is correct is gives me the following error

> Host-relative URL path must start with a '/'

Below is the webhook url for receiving the fax

> https://pakistanourhome.org/fax/fax/sent

"if you paste the above url in the browser it will work fine"

I am not sure what i am dong wrong here. It will be great if someone can guide me through this.

Comment: can you show some code related to setup path?

Comment: When do you receive that error? And what TwiML do you send back to the webhook?

Comment: Thanks for your time guys issues is fixed now all i added was   www. in the webhook url and it started to work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the webhook url from

```
https://pakistanourhome.org/fax/fax/sent
```

to

```
https://www.pakistanourhome.org/fax/fax/sent
```